# unswap caps and control

Tags: keyboard, xorg, evdev

I recently changed my keymapping to neo, however, Capslock is still swapped with the control-key.
`/etc/default/keyboard` contains just `XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt"`
`.xinitrc` only loads my sound drivers and my windowmanager.
`.xinputrc` contains `run_im ibus`
If I add a script to `.xinitrc`, which runs `setxkbmap de neo -option` , `setxkbmap -query` still tells me `options:    ctrl:swapcaps`

How can I debug this? I really don't want caps to be swapped with control anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From setxkbmap man page:

> -option name
>
> Specifies the name of an option to determine the components which make up the keyboard description;  multiple options may be specified, one per -option flag. Note  that setxkbmap adds options specified in the command line to the options that were set before (as saved in root window properties). If you want to replace all previously spec‐ified options, use the -option flag with an empty argument first.

That is -option flag with no argument should do the trick:

`setxkbmap -option`